# How to vectorize a function in R

Tags: r, function, vectorization, trading

I need some help vectorizing the following code because I believe that it will become more efficient. However i do not know how to begin... I created a loop that goes through `z`. `z` has 3 columns and 112847 rows, which might be a reason it takes a long time. The 3 columns contain numbers that are used in the `MACD()` function...

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

# get stock data 
getSymbols('LUNA')

#Choose the Adjusted Close of a Symbol
stock <- Ad(LUNA)

#Create matrix for returns only
y <- stock

#Create a "MATRIX" by choosing the Adjusted Close 
Nudata3 <- stock

#Sharpe Ratio Matrix
SR1<- matrix(NA, nrow=1)

# I want to create a table with all possible combinations from the ranges below
i = c(2:50)
k = c(4:50)
j = c(2:50)

# stores possible combinations into z
z <- expand.grid(i,k,j)
colnames(z)<- c("one","two","three")            

n = 1
stretches <- length(z[,1])

while (n < stretches){ 

# I am trying to go through all the values in "z"
Nuw <- MACD((stock), nFast=z[n,1], nSlow=z[n,2], nSig=z[n,3], maType="EMA")

colnames(Nuw) <- c("MACD","Signal")  #change the col names to create signals
x <- na.omit(merge((stock), Nuw))

x$sig <- NA

# Create trading signals                            

sig1 <- Lag(ifelse((x$MACD <= x$Signal),-1, 0)) # short when MACD < SIGNAL 
sig2 <- Lag(ifelse((x$MACD >= x$Signal),1, 0))  # long when MACD > SIGNAL 
x$sig <- sig1 + sig2



#calculate Returns
ret <- na.omit(ROC(Ad(x))*x$sig)
colnames(ret)<- c(paste(z[n,1],z[n,2],z[n,3],sep=","))
x <- merge(ret,x)
y <- merge(y,ret) #This creates a MATRIX with RETURNs ONLY
Nudata3 <- merge(Nudata3, x)

((mean(ret)/sd(ret)) * sqrt(252))  -> ANNUAL # Creates a Ratio
ANNUAL->Shrat                                # stores Ratio into ShRat
SR1 <- cbind(SR1,Shrat)                      # binds all ratios as it loops

n <- (n+1)

}
```

I would like to know how to vectorize the `MACD()` function, to speed up the process since the length of `stretches` is approx. 112847. It takes my computer quite some time to go through the loop itself.

Comment: Please provide some [reproducible code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Specifically, because I'm not familiar with pulling trading data, I don't know what `Ad()` is, nor what `LUNA` is (are you referring to the stock symbol LUNA?). Also, what is `MACD` supposed to be doing?

Comment: What evidence that you have that MACD is your speed problem? You're doing a lot of merges in a while loop. That's got to be slow. You might be better off asking a question about how to accomplish what you actually want to do efficiently and then providing your code as an example of what you've tried.

Comment: @r2evans `Ad()` is the adjusted close of the stock data. Yes LUNA is the trading Symbol. I updated the code to require the packages used. Also the `MACD()` is "The MACD was developed by Gerald Appel and is probably the most popular price oscillator. The MACD function documented in this page compares a fast moving average (MA) of a series with a slow MA of the same series. It can be used as a generic oscillator for any univariate series, not only price."

Comment: +1 because all information a provided now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost - case specific optimization - remove the cases where `nFast > nSlow` as it doesn't make sense technically.

Secondly - you are creating objects and copying them over and over again. This is very expensive.

Thirdly - you can code this better perhaps by creating a matrix of signals in one loop and doing rest of the operations in vectorized manner.

I would code what you are doing something like this.

Please read help pages of `mapply`, `do.call`, `merge` and `sapply` if you don't understand.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("LUNA")

#Choose the Adjusted Close of a Symbol
stock <- Ad(LUNA)

# I want to create a table with all possible combinations from the ranges below
i = c(2:50)
k = c(4:50)
j = c(2:50)

# stores possible combinations into z
z <- expand.grid(i,k,j)
```

**IMO : This is where your first optimization should be. Remove cases where i > k**

```
z <- z[z[,1]<z[,2], ]
```

It reduces the number of cases from `112847` to `57575`

```
#Calculate only once. No need to calculate this in every iteration.
stockret <- ROC(stock)

getStratRet <- function(nFast, nSlow, nSig, stock, stockret) {
    x  <- MACD((stock), nFast=nFast, nSlow=nSlow, nSig=nSig, maType="EMA")
    x <- na.omit(x)
    sig <- Lag(ifelse((x$macd <= x$signal),-1, 0)) + Lag(ifelse((x$macd >= x$signal),1, 0))
    return(na.omit(stockret * sig))
}

RETURNSLIST <- do.call(merge, mapply(FUN = getStratRet, nFast = z[,1], nSlow = z[,2], nSig = z[,3], MoreArgs = list(stock = stock, stockret = stockret), SIMPLIFY = TRUE))

getAnnualSharpe <- function(ret) {
    ret <- na.omit(ret)
    return ((mean(ret)/sd(ret)) * sqrt(252))
}


SHARPELIST <- sapply(RETURNSLIST, FUN = getAnnualSharpe)
```

Results will be as below. Which column belongs to which combo of `i`, `j`, `k` is trivial.

```
head(RETURNSLIST[, 1:3])
##            LUNA.Adjusted LUNA.Adjusted.1 LUNA.Adjusted.2
## 2007-01-10   0.012739026    -0.012739026               0
## 2007-01-11  -0.051959739     0.051959739               0
## 2007-01-12  -0.007968170    -0.007968170               0
## 2007-01-16  -0.007905180    -0.007905180               0
## 2007-01-17  -0.005235614    -0.005235614               0
## 2007-01-18   0.028315920    -0.028315920               0

SHARPELIST
##   LUNA.Adjusted LUNA.Adjusted.1 LUNA.Adjusted.2 LUNA.Adjusted.3 LUNA.Adjusted.4 LUNA.Adjusted.5 LUNA.Adjusted.6 
##      0.04939150     -0.07428392             NaN      0.02626382     -0.06789803     -0.22584987     -0.07305477 
## LUNA.Adjusted.7 LUNA.Adjusted.8 LUNA.Adjusted.9 
##     -0.05831643     -0.08864845     -0.08221986 



system.time(
+ RETURNSLIST <- do.call(merge, mapply(FUN = getStratRet, nFast = z[1:100,1], nSlow = z[1:100,2], nSig = z[1:100,3], MoreArgs = list(stock = stock, stockret = stockret), SIMPLIFY = TRUE)),
+ SHARPELIST <- sapply(RETURNSLIST, FUN = getAnnualSharpe)
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   2.28    0.00    2.29
```

Comment: are you referring to `x$MACD <= x$Signal` ?, how can i follow through without copying over and over?

Comment: No - for MACD indicator `nFast > nSlow`  doesn't make sense

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the code above, but I have one question. How long does it take for your computer to run the code? I now believe that it might be my computer that is slow as it take a long time to run the code

Comment: You can't speed things up beyond certain point. I updated the timing of calculations for 100 iterations in my answer above. About 2.29 seconds.

Comment: Ok it takes my computer approximately the same for 100 iterations... I was worried because it was taking a long time for the full length. Thanks once again I appreciate it!